# Snapchat on computer or alternative

Tags: android, google-apps, emulator, snapchat

there is a good alternative to Snapchat for pc? I searched on the Google and I found bluestacks emulator for android applications. I think this emulator wants good requirements for run properly on the computer. I have dell inspiron 3537 with 8GB ram and i7 processor and I think it works. Can I talk with my friends with this snapchat through bluestacks? I found [this](http://storychimes.com/apps-for-pc/free-download-snapchat-for-pc) tutorial. Have you encountered this problem? Thanks!

Comment: (1) Which operating system are you using? (2) Is it required that the alternative works with the existing Snapchat network? (3) If it’s not required (i.e., you would be happy with a separate network), which features do you need exactly? (not everyone knows Snapchat)

Comment: (1) Windows 8.1 (3) Something like  Whatsapp with emoticons and photo sharing

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can recommend [SnapMeNow](http://www.snapmenow.com/),which is a webapp it does not require any installations on a PC & it uses your computer’s camera to take a picture that you can send to up to 100 recipients via a hyperlink. That image self-destructs Snapchat-style after an interval of up to 10 seconds.

Related source :[source](http://www.buzzfeed.com/josephbernstein/snapmenow-is-snapchat-for-your-computer?utm_term=4ldqpia)