# Is there a snapchat emulator for PC?

Tags: windows, social-networks, emulator

My friends are begging me to get snapchat.  My IOS operating system is too bad, and my phone is a 3G so I can't upgrade it.

**Is there a snapchat emulator for Windows?**

*Similar question: [Snapchat on computer or alternative](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13879/snapchat-on-computer-or-alternative)*

Answer (score 1):

There is no [emulator](http://www.andyroid.net/bundledapps/snapchat-for-pc-free-download-windows-78xp) of snapchat itself (that I am aware of). However there are plenty of android emulators available for PC with support for the google play store, meaning  you can [install snapchat onto the emulated android OS](http://www.bluestacks.com/apps/social/snapchat-app-on-pc.html) the same way you would install on a phone or tablet.

Android emulators like Andyroid or BlueStacks will do what you need (both have been linked above).

Alternatively you could try [running the x86 port of android as a virtual machine on VirtualBox](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/).

Answer (score 0):

As above user said,,there is no any snap chat emulator.

But yet available android emulators ain't good in performance wise and most of them a too laggy no matter how the plenty memory you got!

the only option is using virtualisation method by installing android-x86 ports on virtualisation softwares like virtualbox ,VMware etc..[Follow this For Installation on VBox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwin-7ftsNXQAhVCBBoKHX3OB_UQFgg2MAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tactig.com%2Finstall-android-6-0-marshmallow-virtualbox-pc%2F&usg=AFQjCNEpSdQjkB8QBkoYUx0S1IdpnaUJ8Q&sig2=fApirFt0IxlZGfbAJ3expQ&bvm=bv.139782543,d.d2s)

The other option is using ready mad android x86 port for pc called [Remix Os](http://www.jide.com/en/remixos).    Every details is available on their website.